# SSMS Error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '('"

Tags: sql-server, view

I am getting the titled error from a number of SQL Server views I am trying to create. They are modified from a MS Access database I'm upgrading to use SQL as the back end. See SQL below:

```
SELECT        dbo.Site_Info_All.SiteID, 
       IIf(dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge, N'Yes', N'No') AS [Fixed Charge], 
       dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge_Date, dbo.MG_Definition.MG_Definition
FROM            dbo.MG_Definition INNER JOIN
                dbo.Site_Info_All ON dbo.MG_Definition.MG_DefinitionID = 
                dbo.Site_Info_All.MG_DefinitionID
```

It looks as though I'm being told that the Fixed_Charge field is not boolean, except that it is. I'm encountering this issue with multiple views.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided that IIF simply wasn't working for whatever reason. An answer to that would be very welcome, btw.

I used

```
SELECT        dbo.Site_Info_All.SiteID, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge = 1 
        THEN N'Yes' 
        ELSE N'No' 
    END AS [Fixed Charge], dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge_Date, 
              dbo.MG_Definition.MG_Definition
FROM          dbo.MG_Definition INNER JOIN
            dbo.Site_Info_All ON dbo.MG_Definition.MG_DefinitionID = 
            dbo.Site_Info_All.MG_DefinitionID
```

That gave me the results I was after, but only after pulling out what little hair I have left.

Comment: "An answer to that would be very welcome, btw." - As I said in the other comment, don't use the designer. It's a holdover from a much, much earlier time, there's no way it's been kept up to date as the language has evolved. They probably ported the darn access code. Just use TSQL in a query window.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `boolean`. It's a `bit`. :)

A `bit` column doesn't directly evaluate to `true` or `false`, the way a `bool` does in other languages. You actually have to compare it to another `bit` value to return the boolean value.

```
declare @bit bit = 1;
if (@bit) print '@bit was true'; -- this does not work
if (@bit = 1) print '@bit = 1 was true'; -- this works
```

What you want is:

```
... IIf(dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge = 1, N'Yes', N'No') ...
```

```
SELECT       dbo.Site_Info_All.SiteID, 
             IIf(dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge = 1, N'Yes', N'No') AS [Fixed Charge], 
             dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge_Date, 
             dbo.MG_Definition.MG_Definition
FROM         dbo.MG_Definition 
INNER JOIN   dbo.Site_Info_All ON dbo.MG_Definition.MG_DefinitionID = dbo.Site_Info_All.MG_DefinitionID
```

Comment: I see, I figured that bits were equivalent. Even so, I had tried doing exactly that, and I get "Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. Unable to parse query text" when attempting to edit the SQL itself.  Then if I try to do this using the GUI section, it places single quotes around the whole field, like "IIf('dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge = 1', N'Yes', N'No') AS [Fixed Charge]", which is also not helpful.  How do I get around this?

Comment: You should not have a single quote before the d in `dbo`, and a single quote after the 1 in `= 1`. Look at my "what you want is:" bit

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it properly.  SSMS puts this in automatically, if I input your "What you want is:" into the GUI, and if I copy and paste it into the SQL section or otherwise edit it there, I get the "Error in list of function arguments" message.

Comment: @Chris I have edited my answer to give you exactly what you should be executing.

Comment: I really appreciate your continued help with this, but having pasted that in (which is what I had done before), I get the error, "Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized. Unable to parse query text".

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwjx4nkv636h0kc/Capture.JPG?dl=0
This is a screenshot, so you can see.

Comment: Oh... that's still inside the MS Access front end. I thought you were working in SQL Server (ie, SSMS). RIght, that makes more sense. Ummm... work inside SSMS, trying to build on SQL server from *within* ms access is just... yeah... nah :)  Also, what SQL version? As a temporary fix, you could try replacing `iif()` with `case`, ie `case when dbo.Site_Info_All.Fixed_Charge = 1 then N'Yes' else N'No' end`

Comment: No, that's in SSMS. I right mouse click on 'Views' and choose 'New View...'

Comment: Oh god, I thought the designers got removed from SSMS. Yeah, OK, just use a query window.

Comment: Ie, instead of clicking "modify" or "design", right click -> script view as -> alter to -> new query window

Comment: Ok, I've investigated a bit more.  If I literally type "iif(2<3,1,2)" into the Column of the designer mode, it puts single quotes around the test - '2<3'. If I amend it in the SQL section, it gives me an error "Error in list of function arguments: '<' not recognized."
Your last comment may be useful, but if I haven't yet created the view, how can I choose to modify it?

Comment: I figured you would create it without the offending column, which would allow you to then alter it and code in the additional column directly via TSQL. Alternatively, just write it from scratch in TSQL in a query window as a `create view` statement.